# XML Schema: Extend xsd:choice so that union (not sequence) of choices is created

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XML Schema

```
<xsd:complexType name="SimpleThing">
    <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xsd:group ref="simpleContent" />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="ExtendedThing">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="SimpleThing">
            <xsd:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element name="qux" />
            </xsd:choice>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:group name="simpleContent">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:element name="foo" />
        <xsd:element name="bar" />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:group>

<xsd:group name="extendedContent">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:group ref="simpleContent" />
        <xsd:element name="qux" />
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:group>

<xsd:element name="root" type="ExtendedThing" />
```

I would like the type `ExtendedThing` to contain `foo`, `bar` and `qux` in arbitrary order. But with this schema, `qux` must come after `foo` and `bar` because a sequence, not a union of the choices is created from the choice of the supertype and the choice of the subtype.

The alternative, replacing the type definition for `ExtendedThing` with

```
<xsd:complexType name="ExtendedThing">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="SimpleThing">
            <xsd:group ref="extendedContent" />
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

doesn't work either, because the [Unique Particle Attribution](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-nonambig) constraint is violated.

Is there any solution to this problem or is it impossible to create a type in XML Schema that is an extension of another type such that the content of the new type is a set of elements (in any order) that is a superset of the content of the supertype?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008622/how-to-extend-a-choice-complextype-without-sequencing-the-choice

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, for practical reasons. The content model of a super-type must always come in entirety before the content model of the sub-type. It helps to keep the implementation of validators fast.