# Making an xsd schema extensible with a typed element

Tags: xsd

Given a schema that defines an element of a certain type, is it possible to allow that type to be extended, but still have that extension element be strongly typed? In other words, add some kind of extension point that can be used from an external schema to add elements that can only be used in this location?

Let's say the schema looks kinda like:

```
<xs:schema …>
  <xs:element name="Match" type="tns:TNodeConstraint" />

  <xs:complexType name="TNodeConstraint">
    <xs:group ref="tns:Expression" />
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:group name="Expression">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="And">
        <xs:complexType … />
      </xs:element>

      <xs:element name="Or">
        <xs:complexType … />
      </xs:element>

      <xs:element name="IsAbstract">
      <xs:element name="IsExtern">

      <!-- Some kind of extension point? -->
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>
</xs>
```

Is it possible to extend the `Expression` group so that a second, external schema could say that I can accept `IsMyCustomConstraint` here, but not `IsMyCustomSortOrder`? So this will be valid:

```
<Match>
  <IsAbstract />
  <IsExtern />
  <IsMyCustomConstraint />
</Match>
```

But this would be invalid?

```
<Match>
  <IsAbstract />
  <IsExtern />
  <IsMyCustomSortOrder />
</Match>
```

- I don't want to use `xs:any` as that would allow putting a "sort order" where a constraint can go.
- I can modify the original schema
- I'm in control of what the namespaces of `IsMyCustomConstraint` and `IsMyCustomSortOrder` would be, and it's not important if they match the original schema or not.

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to allow that type to be extended, but still have that extension element be strongly typed?

Definitely - this is described in detail, with examples, here: https://www.w3.org/TR/2000/WD-xmlschema-0-20000225/#DerivExt. As far as I can tell, you just need to declare one or more complex types that are extensions of your base type 'TNodeConstraint'.

XML schema has a rich set of facilities to support type inheritance including:

- abstract base types (base type must be extended or restricted before use)
- extension (new type allows more values than the base type)
- restriction (new type allows fewer values than the base type)
- control of whether further extensions/restrictions are allowed (final/block attributes)

I don't see any need to use a separate XSD for the extensions, although you can if you want to. You may find it useful to know about xsi:type, abstract types and the block/final attributes - all are described the XML Schema Part 0 - Primer mentioned above.

Comment: But how do I add an element of this new type into the choice inside the `Expression`?

Comment: Fair question - you are asking how to extend a choice group. I think this thread will be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008622/how-to-extend-a-choice-complextype-without-sequencing-the-choice. You cannot do it by complex type extension _only_, but it is possible to create extensible schemas. You just have to understand a lot about the mechanisms that XML Schema allows.

Comment: Thanks. I did try to make a solution based on substitution groups, but hit problems with duplicate element names since the substituting elements have to be global.