# Extending a choice in XSD

Tags: xml, xsd

I have read both [How to extend a choice complexType without sequencing the choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008622/how-to-extend-a-choice-complextype-without-sequencing-the-choice) and [XML Schema: Extend xsd:choice so that union (not sequence) of choices is created](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216313/xml-schema-extend-xsdchoice-so-that-union-not-sequence-of-choices-is-created?lq=1). My question is related but slightly different. I have an XML Schema with a number of different `complexTypes` that all look like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="Type_NNN">
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="indiv_NNN" type="Indiv_NNN" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="common-element" type="CommmonElement" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="commonAtt-001" type="xs:string" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="commonAtt-002" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="commonAtt-003" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="commonAtt-004" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="commonAtt-005" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="commonAtt-006" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="commonAtt-007" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" 
                  use="optional" default="0"/>
    <xs:attribute name="commonAtt-008" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
    <xs:attribute name="indivAtt-NNN" type="xs:string" use="optional"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

that is, most of the content is common, except for the items marked "NNN". Is there a way to use inheritance so that the common elements have to be set up only once? It is clear that I can do this for the attributes, but the `<xs:choice>` is tripping me up for the elements. Is my only option to put both

```
        <xs:element name="indiv_NNN" type="Indiv_NNN" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="common-element" type="CommmonElement" minOccurs="0"/>
```

into the `<xs:extension>`? There must be a better way!

Answer (score 0):

If your primary goal is to avoid repeating yourself, the simplest approach is probably to use a named model group:

```
<group name="basic-choice">
  <choice>
    <element name="common-element" 
             type="tns:CommonElement" 
             minOccurs="0"/>
  </
</
```

All types that share tns:common-element refer to this group:

```
<complexType name="Type_NNN">
  <choice>
    <element name="indiv_NNN" 
             type="tns:Indiv_NNN" 
             minOccurs="0"/>
    <group ref="tns:basic-choice"/>
  </
</
```

Answer (score 0):

`xs:choice` is not extensible. Extensions would go into a derived type, and extension content would go into a separate block occurring after the original content.

There are good strategies for building base types so that they are very extensible. If you can modify the base type, a good method for making it extensible would be to have it include an element that is meant to be the head of a substitution group. Then any extension can provide an element substitutable for that head element.

For example, you could build the base type with an extension point head:

```
<complexType name="base_type">
  <sequence>
    <element ref="base_ns:base_extension_point_head" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
  </sequence>
</complexType>

<element name="base_extension_point_head" abstract="true"/>
```

Then an extension would substitute for the the head element:

```
<element name="extension" type="extension_ns:type" substitutionGroup="base_ns:base_extension_point_head"/>
```

NIEM uses this strategy to ensure that types in reference schemas are extensible. NIEM calls them "augmentation points". See [the NIEM naming and design rules](http://reference.niem.gov/niem/specification/naming-and-design-rules/3.0/NIEM-NDR-3.0-2014-07-31.html#section_10.4) for an example.